# Carrierwave, MiniMagick - NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

On staging, I'm facing the following error on uploading and resizing an image through carrierwave and minimagick. On local everything works fine.

carrierwave (0.9.0)
mini_magick (3.7.0)

```
irb(main):003:0> PicturePost.create(remote_content_url: 'http://www.imagpress.com/img/slider/slider_1.jpg')
NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick.rb:24:in `choose_processor'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick.rb:64:in `mogrify?'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:360:in `run_command'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:171:in `valid?'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:140:in `create'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:48:in `read'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:111:in `block in open'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:260:in `manipulate!'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:176:in `resize_to_fill'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:85:in `block in process!'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
9 levels...
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/download.rb:65:in `download!'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:353:in `remote_url='
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:203:in `remote_content_url='
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:44:in `remote_content_url='
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
from (irb):3
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/deploy/apps/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Had forgotten to install imagemagick on my new server.
This solved the issue for me

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: You probably just saved me hours! Thanks for answering your question, +1

Comment: This was it after trying eight other things. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs when MiniMagick looks for the commands `mogrify` or `gm` and fails to find either one.

As mentioned in another answer, you need to make sure that ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick is installed with a command such as

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

However, this problem can also occur if ImageMagick is installed in a non-standard location and is not available on the path of the Rails process.  For example, if you install from source into `/usr/local/bin`, that location might not be on the path.  In this case, to ensure that your path is set up correctly, add this line to `application.rb`, `environments/production.rb`, or some other appropriate place:

```rb
ENV['PATH'] += File::PATH_SEPARATOR + '/usr/local/bin'
```

Note that your path might be different depending on how the application is started, e.g. from the command line vs. from a system init file, so adding a line like this is important to ensure that MiniMagick will work correctly under all circumstances.

Under Linux, you can inspect the path of a running Rails process by finding the pid and then looking at `/proc/<pid>/environ`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like its a problem with mini_magick 3.7.0. Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1282)

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew & Yosemite-centric Answer:

http://thornelabs.net/2014/12/08/libpng-not-symlinking-when-installing-imagemagick-on-os-x-yosemite.html

Sure, you'll need to reinstall ImageMagick, but if running

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Gives you an error like:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man5/png.5
/usr/local/share/man/man5 is not writable.
...
```

First, check that your username has permission with

```
ls -al /usr/local/share/man
```

if you don't, you'll need to run

```
sudo chown -R yourusername /usr/local/share/man/man5
brew link libpng
```

Hope this saves someone some hours.

-B

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the yum package manager (like I am for AWS Opsworks). You can do

```
yum install ImageMagick
```

note: ImageMagick spelt as camelcase

Answer (score 0):

If you use some IDE probably the problem can solved just by restarting of IDE. I spend so much time trying to find solution for this problem. And this simple operation worked for me.

Comment: It could be a weird problem in development environment, but he said the problem occurs only on staging, not develepment. Probably on staging he uses `nano`, `vim` or other code editor, but not an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who are using Rails and using mini_magick instead, change the version to 3.5 in your gemfile, as 3.6 is broken for image upload with mini_magick and simply doesn't work with version 3.7.

Comment: Downgrading to 3.5 is causing: Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - identify